# Flatten/Concatenate an array to a list for match in excel formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, concatenation

I have a table of data in excel which has double header rows.  I would like to perform an hlookup against this table using a flattened version of the two headers.  For example, if my data were like this

```
    A      B      C     D       E      F
 1  cat    cat    boy    boy    egg    egg
 2  1      2      1      4      3      1
 3  val1  val2   val3   val4   val5   val6
 4  val7  val8   val9   val10  val11  val12
 5  val13 val14  val15  val16  val17  val18
 6  val19 val20  val21  val22  val23  val24
```

I want to  `match` something like this: `=match("boy4", concatenate(A1:A6,b1:b6)) )` with a result of `4.`

This doesn't work though, because  `concatenate(A1:A6,b1:b6)` returns `egg1` as a regular formula, or `cat1` as an array formula.

Is there a way *within a single function* (without creating a separate row to hold those values) to generate a list like `cat1   cat2   boy1   boy4   egg3   egg1` that can then be wrapped inside `match`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CONCATENATE()` cannot accept a range of cells as arguments. Instead you just have to concatenate the ranges yourself with `&`. This is an array formula, and must be confirmed with ctrl+shift+enter.

```
=MATCH("boy4",A1:F1&A2:F2,0)
```

Comment: Beautiful - I had just figured out a kludgy way to do it involving some string splitting: `match(1, if(a1:a6=left("boy3",3),1,0)+if(right("boy3",1,0)`-ctl-shift-enter - except with my actual data, it was even uglier, because my string parts aren't always length  3&1.    Your solution works perfectly, improves my understanding of Excel, and is elegant.